# jump algorithm isn't working when reaching a block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/whZ44/17/

As you can see in my jsfiddle when the ball reach a block the jump function is not working.I know i am missing something in my algorithm that i am using to make the ball jump but i can't figure it out i would appreciate some help from you

```
if (InAir) {
    if (InAir == 1) {
        if (ball.y > jumpMaxHeight) {
            ball.y -= gravity;
        } else {
            InAir = 2;
        }
    }
    if (InAir == 2) {
        if (ball.y < 390) {
            ball.y += gravity;
        } else {
            ball.y = 390;
            InAir = false;
            ball.color = "black";
        }
    }
} else if (keydown.up && !InAir) {
    InAir = 1;
    ball.color = "#4285F4";
}

for (var j = 0; j < Blocks.collection.length; j++) {
    if (Collision(ball, Blocks.collection[j])) {
        //console.log("collision");
        ball.y = (Blocks.collection[j].blockY - ball.radius) ;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe here is something to start with: http://jsfiddle.net/d247V/3/

I updated the jump to have a default jump of 80 (high enough to get to next platform), and then on keydown.up i update that with the current ball.y position + the default

I think though the issue is how you are tracking the ball being in the air or not, when a collision is detected, the ball is technically no longer in the air, but you didn't have anything saying as such, see code snipped below basically how @mainguy said but with a slight modification to not keep reassigning ball.y, in the fiddle it works pretty well:

```
      if( InAir )
      {
          for (var j = 0; j < Blocks.collection.length; j++) {
              if (Collision(ball, Blocks.collection[j])) {
                //console.log("collision");
                var calc = (Blocks.collection[j].blockY - ball.radius);
                  if( ball.y != calc ) {
                    ball.y = calc;
                    ball.color = "black";
                    InAir = 0;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

My fiddle though broke the gravity portion of the code, because you now need to also know if the x of the circle is passed the x barrier of the rectangle, and fall if not.  So this is by no means a complete solution, but if you jump and go right or left from a barrier, the gravity process works as expected as long as no collisions exist, you will fall down to the bottom.  There are slight other tweaks but I think you will be able to find them by the comment `//Tweaked` next to the parts I added.

Comment: thank you for updating the fiddle you was very helpful though i've changed all my algorithm after some deep research and here is my new version of the game  : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/6eeKH/5/ as you can see the gravity works pretty well and it don't float in air when on a block and leave and now i am looking forward to build some levels thank you :D

Comment: looks great! glad I could help. I enjoyed messing around with it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your collision detection is working pretty well.
Its the gameloop that has some issues.
You should not do a collision detection on keypress up because this will only fire once. You need to check for collides all the time while the ball is in the air.
Like so:

```
   ... } else if (keydown.up && !InAir) {
        InAir = 1;
        ball.color = "#4285F4";

      }

      if (InAir){
          for (var j = 0; j < Blocks.collection.length; j++) {
          if (Collision(ball, Blocks.collection[j])) {
            //console.log("collision");
            ball.y = (Blocks.collection[j].blockY - ball.radius) ;
            InAir=false;
          }
        }
      }
```

With his code you can jump on the first plattform. (Note also that i changed ball.y positioning).

But some issues remain:

- The Ball can not leave the plattform because as soon as he is airborne the collision with the plattform he is lying on kicks in.
- If you move the Ball left or right over the plattform border it would be way more fun if he starts falling down again, instead of hovering in the air. (Trust me, i played some games).

Maybe you should delay collision detection until the ball has gained some height to escape the collision detection.
I update your fiddle and converted it to a plunker (with firebug you have way better debugging functionality here) [Play with me!](http://plnkr.co/edit/wgezIpvv0yHQNDuvYqpM?p=preview)

Not a perfect answer but i hope this will help you.

Comment: man this is a bug the hovering in the air it should fall to the ground again

Comment: Wot? No, it's not a bug, it's a ball! You call it ball in your own routine. A bug usualy has six legs and a high propability that it CAN hower in the air :-)

Comment: I mean a game error the ball should not float in the air instead it should fall to the ground when it's outside the border of the block :)